# Does a simple solution exist for programmatically detecting add/edit/deletes locally and updating visual studio online accordingly?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, team-explorer-everywhere

I have code that generates SQL scripts that will run nightly. I want to check this into source control each night, so I get a history of changes to tables etc. as well as picking up new tables and when tables are deleted.

I have a team project created in Visual Studio Online.

From looking online it looks like there's no reliable way of automatically picking up changes locally and committing them to VSO. I'd have to create something that compares what I have locally to what is in VSO, which to me seems error-prone.

If I use the command line utility it looks like I have to tell it what is added and deleted (i can't just check everything out, then add/edit/delete my local files, then commit).
I've also looked into the [Team Foundation Server class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.teamfoundationserver.aspx%20%22TeamFoundationServer%22%20class), but that's obsolete.

---

**TL;DR:** Is there anything I can to do easily sync local changes (add/edit/delete) to VSO, without having to tell it what's been changed?

Comment: Have you considered that you're approaching this from the wrong direction? Instead of picking up database changes from the databases, use SSDT and have the people working on the databases make their changes to the canonical database schema, then automate the generation and execution of the database schema change scripts via a build/release pipeline.

Comment: I'd like to put something in place with minimal/no changes to the way we work currently. Thanks for the input though, I agree it's a better way of working generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just check in the changed from your workspace?

If you have a Local Workspace that includes the folder that you generate the SQL into you can just call tf.exe checkin to get all of the changed into TFS.

+Daniel is right.

Comment: Isn't it more complex than that? I think I need to call add and delete too. Plus checkout for any edits.

Comment: Not if you are using the TFS 2012+ API. If you use Local Workspaces then it should detect the changes...